# Gitlab CI/CD git push POMs changes in all stage's jobs

Tags: spring-boot, maven, gitlab, microservices, gitlab-ci

I made simple microservices structure in spring boot (three modules) and I wanted to conigure gitlab ci/cd for autoincrement version number in pom of changed microservice. So I created step in my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
.increment-version-module:
  stage: increment version
  image: ssmolinski9/docker-adoptopenjdk-11-maven-node
  except:
    variables:
      - $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN == "login"
      - $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
  before_script:
    - git config --global user.email "mymail"
    - git config --global push.default matching
    - git config --global user.name "myname"
    - git config --global user.password "$CI_INCREMENTION_PWD"
  script:
    - NUMBER=$(grep \<\/version $MODULE/pom.xml | head -n 1 | cut -d '>' -f2 | cut -d '<' -f1)
    - NUMBER_1=$(echo $NUMBER | cut -d '.' -f1)
    - NUMBER_2=$(echo $NUMBER | cut -d '.' -f2)
    - NUMBER_3=$(echo $NUMBER | cut -d '.' -f3)
    - NUMBER_3=$((NUMBER_3+1))
    - NUMBER_new="$NUMBER_1"."$NUMBER_2"."$NUMBER_3"
    - sed -i 's/\<version\>$NUMBER\<\/version\>/\<version\>$NUMBER_new\<\/version\>/g' $MODULE/pom.xml
    - echo $NUMBER_new
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS -pl $MODULE versions:set -B -DnewVersion=$NUMBER_new -f pom.xml
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS -pl $MODULE versions:commit -B -DprocessAllModules -f pom.xml
    - git commit -a -m ''$MODULE' POM Version Increment '$NUMBER_new''
    - git pull https://myname:$CI_INCREMENTION_PWD@gitlab.com/url/to/my/repo/api.git HEAD:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME --prune --rebase
    - git push https://myname:$CI_INCREMENTION_PWD@gitlab.com/url/to/my/repo/api.git HEAD:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -u -f
```

Then I created three jobs for every module I have, eg:

```
increment-discovery-service:
  extends:
    - .discovery-service
    - .increment-version-module
  resource_group: incrementing
```

I though it work, my pipeline is in SUCCESS state but... When I pulled my changes only one (last) of three commits still exists. Everything inside pipeline log is correct (new version, create commit, push), but I think -f option in git push is messing up.

[Last commits on my branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKJqS.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you need the build number in git, is it no sufficient to have it in the artifact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. I have to pull from $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME instead of HEAD:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME. I changed it and everything seems to work correct. I'll present full solution if someone need it in the future.

My modules structure:

```
--discovery-service
---pom.xml 
---.gitlab-ci.yml 
--dummy-service
---pom.xml
---.gitlab-ci.yml
--gateway-service
---pom.xml
---.gitlab-ci.yml
-.gitlab-ci.yml
-.pom.xml
```

So I have pom.xml and .gitlab-ci.yml in each microservice's module and one for root.

Each .gitlab-ci.yml inside microservice looks like:

```
.discovery-service:
  variables:
    MODULE: "discovery-service"
  only:
    changes:
      - "discovery-service/**/*"
```

In main .gitlab-ci.yml we have to include microservices' configurations:

```
include:
  - local: discovery-service/.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: dummy-service/.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: gateway-service/.gitlab-ci.yml
```

.increment-version-module I listed in the first post. Only change pull from $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME without HEAD. Last thing you have to make job for every module:

```
increment-discovery-service:
  extends:
    - .discovery-service
    - .increment-version-module
  resource_group: incrementing

increment-dummy-service:
  extends:
    - .dummy-service
    - .increment-version-module
  resource_group: incrementing

increment-gateway-service:
  extends:
    - .gateway-service
    - .increment-version-module
  resource_group: incrementing
```